# Cambiar el estado de un componente desde otro componente en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, props

Como puedo hacer para cambiar el estado de un componente que se encuentra en otro fichero.js?
En concreto, tengo un tablero (una matriz) y cada vez que haga click en una celda quiero obtener su fila y su columna, para fijar la casilla de inicio y la de fin, para ello me he tenido que crear cuatro estados que son filaInicio, columnaIncio,filaFin y columna fin y quiero cambiar estas props desde el componente de la columna que contiente un [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no subas capturas de tu codigo, mas bien sube el codigo para poder copiar y pegar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

una manera de poder cambiar el estado de un componente desde otro es pasando la funcion del hook mediante props, aqui un ejemplo

```
const oneComponent = () => {
 //estableces el hook
 const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
 //al component le pasamos el valor del hook y la funcion para actualizar el hook
 return <TwoComponent setNumber={setNumber} number={number}/>
}

//se recibe mediate props los valores que pasamos
const TwoComponent = ({number, setNumber}) => {

  const changeNumber = ()=>{
    setNumer(number + 1)
  }


  return(
   <div>
     <p>el numero es {number} </p>
     //al hacer click se suma de a uno
     <button onClick={changeNumber}>
      sumar
     </button>
   </div>
  )
}
```

de querer pasar varios parametros para controlar los estados del componente padre, lo que podrias hacer es una funcion que haga cierta accion, ej

```
const oneComponent = () => {
 const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)

 const sumar = () => {
   //aqui la logica de la funcion
   setNumber(number + 1)
 }
 
 return <TwoComponent sumar={sumar}/>
}

//se recibe mediate props los valores que pasamos
const TwoComponent = ({sumar}) => {

  return(
   <div>
     <button onClick={sumar}>
      sumar
     </button>
   </div>
  )
}
```

//al hacer esto estarás controlando el estado del componente padre desde el componente hijo, con esto podrias crear funciones en el componente padre que hagan cierto trabajo y puedes ejecutar desde el componente hijo

Comment: Ya pero el problema va mas allá haciendo esto, porque tendría que pasarle por props 8 parametros, ya que necesito la posicion (x,y) de la posicion inicial y la posicion (x,y) de la posicion final y creo que es un poco raro asi

Comment: ahora edito mi respuesta